# How to call a GetInstance from Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm reverse engineering a control plugin for a laptop and trying to figure out how to call the methods that emulate what the "app" is doing. It's written in C#, so I thought I could just use PowerShell to call methods on it.
I've used DotPeek to figure out that everything is handled into a single DLL which implements the methods that I want to access.

The class looks like:

```
namespace Vendor.package1.package2.SomePlugin
{
  internal class SomeClass : IInterfaceThatIWant, ...
  {

    ~SomeClass()
    {
    }
  

    public RequestObject SetSomething()
    {
      ... method that I want to use
    }

    public ResponseObject GetSomething()
    {
      ...
    }
  
    private SomeClass()
    {
      ...
    }

    public static SomeClass GetInstance()
    {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Inside PowerShell, I've tried:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\pathtodll\x64\vendor.dll"
```

and

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("c:\pathtodll\x64\vendor.dll")
```

...which did not show any error, so I assume both worked.

Next I'm trying:

```
[Vendor.package1.package2.SomePlugin.SomeClass]::GetInstance()
   Unable to find type [Vendor.package1.package2.SomePlugin.SomeClass].  
New-Object Vendor.package1.package2.SomePlugin.SomeClass
   New-Object : Cannot find type [Vendor.package1.package2.SomePlugin.SomeClass]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
[Vendor.package1.package2.SomePlugin.SomeClass]::GetInstance
   Unable to find type [Vendor.package1.package2.SomePlugin.SomeClass].
```

and various other permutations but I cannot get a class handle.

Comment: Have you tried putting the DLL in a folder with the same name and do `Import-Module that folder` or `Import-Module that\folder\that.dll` ?

Comment: Yes, the dll is successfully loaded, I can access the public classes

Comment: I've managed to get further: $assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("pathto.dll") then $assembly.GetTypes() lists tha class that I want first, then $t = $assembly.GetTypes()[0] then $m = $t.GetMethod("GetInstance") then $agent = $m.Invoke($null,$null)

Comment: Note that ```SomeClass``` is ```internal``` in your example which means it’s not *normally* visible to code outside the dll. You can use reflection (e.g. ```$assembly.GetTypes()```) to access it, but ```new-object``` can’t see the type because it’s not ```public```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain a reference to the non-public `SomeClass` type, there are a couple of options:

### 1. Have `Add-Type` return all types from the assembly

`Add-Type` has a `-PassThru` switch that'll return all types found in the loaded assembly, regardless of access:

```
# Import assembly out emit types
$VendorTypes = Add-Type -Path "c:\pathtodll\x64\vendor.dll" -PassThru

# Filter the types for the one we need
$SomeClassType = $VendorTypes.Where({$_.FullName -eq 'Vendor.package1.package2.SomePlugin.SomeClass'})

# Invoke public static `GetInstance()` method
$SomeInstance = $SomeClassType::GetInstance()

$SomeInstance.SetSomething()
```

### 2. Discover type metadata via `Assembly.GetTypes()`

[As you've already found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532201/how-to-call-a-getinstance-from-powershell#comment112344903_63532201), `[Assembly]::LoadFrom(...)` also returns an `Assembly` object through which we can discovery the types it contains:

```bsh
# Load assembly, hold on to Assembly reference
$VendorAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("c:\pathtodll\x64\vendor.dll")

# Get all contained types
$VendorTypes = $VendorAssembly.GetTypes()

# Same steps as above ...
```

> [...] the dll is successfully loaded, I can access the public classes

In this case you can also get to the Assembly via one of the public types:

```
$VendorAssembly = [Vendor.package1.package2.SomePublicClass].Assembly
```

### 3. Discover assembly metadata from `AppDomain`

What if you didn't call `Add-Type` or `[Assembly]::LoadFrom()` directly, but are trying to discover non-public types exposed by an assembly in the GAC or loaded indirectly by a module?

Thankfully, we can make the runtime tell us all the assemblies that have already been loaded via the `[AppDomain]` class:

```bsh
# Enumerate all loaded assemblies
$AllAssemblies = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

# Filter for the vendor assembly in question
$VendorAssembly = $AllAssemblies.Where({ $_.Location -like "C:\pathtodll\x64\vendor.dll" })

# Same steps as above
```

---

### Invoking non-public members

If `GetInstance` is also non-public you might have to use reflection to access it:

```bsh
# Use reflection to obtain a reference to the GetInstance method
$GetInstanceMethod = $SomeClassType.GetMethod("GetInstance", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'Static,NonPublic')

# Static methods need no invocation target, second argument is parameter args for the target method
$SomeInstance = $GetInstanceMethod.Invoke($null, @())
```

For invoking instance methods you need to pass a reference to the target instance:

```
# Use reflection to obtain a reference to the SetSomething method, 
# Notice `Instance` instead of `Static` in the list of binding flags
$SetSomethingMethod = $SomeClassType.GetMethod("SetSomething", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'Instance,NonPublic')

# Pass the SomeClass instance we created in the previous example as the invocation target:
$RequestObject = $SetSomethingMethod.Invoke($SomeInstance, @())
```

Comment: This answer is quite informative, thank you for always sharing your knowledge.